# JS get value of generated textnode

Tags: javascript, textnode

I have this Javascript in a for loop:

```
renderAElements[i] = document.createElement ("a");
        renderAElements[i].setAttribute("href", "#");
        renderAElements[i].setAttribute("class", "expander");
        renderAElements[i].appendChild(expand);

        alert (renderAElements[i].nodeValue);
```

where expand is created as:

```
var expand = document.createTextNode("+");
```

The alert, which is meant to return the link text of each created element returns null. Why is this?

Comment: Use el.nodeValue

See this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546924/js-get-value-of-generated-textnode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are trying to get the `nodeValue` of the Element node and not the Text node.

```
alert (renderAElements[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Comment: Cheers. Spotted the problem the same time your answer appeared.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the a element contains another element and not a value.  If you want to get the text out of the node you'll need to do either

```
renderAElements.childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

or

```
renderAElements.innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](http://help.dottoro.com/ljkuedch.php)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetTextNode () {
            var textContainer = document.getElementById ("textContainer");
            var textNode = textContainer.firstChild;
            alert (textNode.data);
        }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="textContainer">This is a simple text in the container.</div>
    <button onclick="GetTextNode ()">Get the contents of the container</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `alert (renderAElements[i].firstChild.nodeValue);`