# How to the text within a pair of tags, like "my head" in "<h1>my head</h1>", by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

E.g.

```
<h1>my head</h1>
```

As I know, the below codes can print the `h1`,

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
alert("tag : "+el.tagName);
```

But, how could I get the text between a pair of tags, i.e. `my head` ?

Comment: Use el.nodeValue

See this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546924/js-get-value-of-generated-textnode

Comment: @DennisPlucinik It doesn't work here.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML)

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
alert("tag : "+el.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

try by `regx`

```
var str = "<h1>my head</h1> ";

var result = str.match(/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/g).map(function(val){
   return val.replace(/<\/?h1>/g,'');
});
```

by [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML)

```
function getValue(){
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
alert(x.innerHTML);
}
```

<sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(el.firstChild.data);
```

This is the normal way with Dom

Answer (score 0):

Use el.firstChild.nodeValue

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]; 
alert("tag : "+el.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Using innerHtml will also return the text value in this case since there are no child elements however if it had any they would also be returned as a string (e.g., my head) which doesn't sound like what you want.